# Storyboards and Delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uistoryboard

In my application I am using storyboards, this is how it's set up:

UIViewController  ->pushing to -> UIViewController ->pushing to -> UIViewController

I have it all working but I can't figure out how I do the delegate between the firstViewController and the thirdViewController. I have looked at how it would normally be done with storyboards (setting the destinationView delegate) but I somehow need to set the thirdViewControllers delegate not the second one. Because there is the ViewController in-between, I don't know how this is done. Any responces are appreciated.Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that you'd like the VC1 to be the delegate of VC2 and VC3?

In VC1 prepareForSegue, you can do as you suggest:

```
VC2 *myVC2 = segue.destinationViewController;
myVC2.delegate = self;
```

In VC2 prepareForSegue, you can also do as you suggest, only indirectly:

```
VC3 *myVC3 = segue.destinationViewController;
myV3.delegate = self.delegate;
```

The headers will look like this:

VC1.h

```
@protocol VC23Delegate <NSObject>
- (void)doSomethingForVC2;
- (void)doSomethingForVC3;
@end
```

VC2.h

```
@protocol VC23Delegate;
@property(weak,nonatomic) id<VC23Delegate> delegate;
```

VC3.h

```
@property(weak,nonatomic) id<VC23Delegate> delegate;
```

Comment: what do u mean by indirectly?

Comment: see how that second case differs slightly?  you set the delegate to self.delegate, not self.

Comment: so im adding a delegate property to VC2 but no protocol

Comment: that's right.  the vc2 and vc3 delegates can be declared identically as conforming to the VC1Delegate protocol.

Comment: in VC2 what should go in @property(nonatomic, retain) id<What goes here>delegate;